# Smoothen edges of a non-binary image

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, python-imaging-library, edges

I'm making some photo-editing tools in `python` using `PIL` (`Python Imaging Library`), and I was trying to make a program which converts a photo to its 'painted' version.

I've managed to make a program which converts a photo into its distinct colours, but the problem is that the algorithm I'm using is operating on every pixel, meaning that the resulting image has very jagged differences between colours.

Ideally, I'd like to smoothen out these edges, but I don't know how!

I've checked out [this site](https://pythontic.com/image-processing/pillow/edge-enhancement-filter) for some help, but the method there produces quite different results to what I need.

My Starting Image:
[image: Starting Image]

My Image with Distinct Colours:
[image: Image with Distinct Colours]

I would like to smoothen the edges in the image above.

Results of using the method which doesn't quite work:
[image: Results of using he method which doesn't quite work]

As you can see, using the technique doesn't smoothen the edges into natural-looking curves; instead it creates jagged edges.

I know I should provide sample output, but suprisingly, I haven't actually got it, so I'll describe it as best as I can. Simply put, I want to smoothen the edges between the different colours.

I've seen something called a Gaussian blur, but I'm not quite sure as to how to apply it here as the answers I've seen always mention some sort of threshold, and are usually to do with binary images, so I don't think it can apply here.

Comment: I would say that your first step is wrong. You should apply a strong non-linear, edge preserving smoothing to the original picture. This will simplify the image, reduce the number of colors you see, but not introduce unnatural edges and colors like these. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48701839/7328782) I show one such filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge enhancement does the opposite of edge smoothing, so this is certainly not the tool you should use.

Unfortunately, there is little that you can do because edge smoothing will indeed smoothen the jaggies, but it will also destroy the true edges, resulting in a blurred image. Edge-preserving smoothing is also a dead-end.

You should have a look at the methods to extract the "cartoon part" of an image. There is a lot of literature on this topic, though often pretty sophisticated.

Comment: About the first part, that was a bit daft on my side :)   But the second bit, you say that it'll destroy the true edges so it's not appropriate; could you post an edge-smoothened version of my image using whichever algorithm you're referring to, and then I could see whether it fits my needs or not?

Comment: @Adi219: apply Gaussian blur and see. You will be disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

You can enhance the quality of your "Image with Distinct Colours" by applying a median filter with a radius of 2:
[image: Image after median filter]

If you want to get "comic-like" dark edges, you can calculate the edges of the original image using a sobel filter, convert the edge map to grayscale, then multiply the resulting edge map with 2, inverse the map and add each non-white pixel of the edge map to the original image. This will result in:

[image: Image after median filter with added edge pixels]

This is of course only a starting point as the result leaves much to be desired, but it should give you a good idea about the basic concept.